# Press push down action in nla. creating less than the original frame length

Tags: animation

[image]

I made an action called walking.

Starts at 288 frames and ends at 311 frames.

If I push this down, the frame will be reduced.

[image]

The last frame is omitted, so it becomes awkward if I repeat it.

Conversely, Deleting a keyframe will reduce the strip to the deleted keyframe, but it will not decrease.

If you look closely, there's a black oblique.

The black oblique area does not produce a strip.

[file]
https://pasteall.org/blend/ddb27b7560584684a6f173be085b7522

Comment: it will cut one frame if you repeat the strip but it should not if you don't. Also I can't see the black oblique, could you please hightlight? You could share your file here: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I checked the black oblique in the picture. And I uploaded the file. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *N* panel of the *Dope Sheet > Item*, disable the *Manual Frame Range* option. [This](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/actions.html#actions-frame-range) is what it is for.

[image]

Comment: Wow... You're the best. Thank you. It's working